# Ajax Calls not Accessing Server Side

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, server-side

I am confused why my Ajax call is not working. Currently, I just need my Ajax method from Client to access my Controller Method. **The alert command is POPING** on my HTML But server side is not accessed from Client. Please advise what am I missing in following:

1. Calling my Controller's Action Method Get Data

   ```
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
         $.get("@Url.Action("GetData","Driver")",function(data){
         $("#dataForSecond").html(data);
         alert("Second ActionResult");
     });
   });
   ```
2. Get Data Method in my Controller just returns:

   ```
    public ActionResult GetData()
   {
       logger.AddLog("INTO 2nd Action Method");
       var secondData = "I m Dummy";
       //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
       logger.AddLog("Setting loggedInAgent Value Again");
      // ViewBag.loggedInAgents = "11";
       return Json(secondData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
   ```
3. For testing I did following in Client side but no REFRESHING took place, only a POP up as before. Whats going on with my code, I have no clue.

   ```
   $(function () {
       var refreshInterval = 5000;
       var url="@Url.Action("GetData","Driver")";
       setInterval(function () {
       $("#View1").load(url);
       }, refreshInterval);
   ```

Comment: Where did you set the value of `secondData` variable ? There is no need to set the ViewBag item in your `GetData` method. Also you are calling the `Show` method and we don't know what is inside that ! Aren't you supposed to call the `GetData` method ?

Comment: Sir, After editing@ I have control in UI/Client for Ajax. But the control doesnt go to Controller Methods/Driver. I have implemented LoGGING in GetData() but logs are never written for this method.

Comment: Do you have any js error in your page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling ActionResult, you need to call JsonResult that's why is not working, see an example bellow:

```
             $.ajax({
                url: '/Product/List',
                type: "GET",
                data: { "nrRecs": 4 },
                async: true,
                dataType: "json",
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                       alert('error');
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('ok');
                }
            });


    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<JsonResult> List(int nrRecs)
    {
        var product = db.products.Take(4);
        return Json(await product.ToListAsync());
    }
```